# Mobx-state-tree: how to rename AnonymousModel to the store name

Tags: javascript, mobx, mobx-state-tree

i am using mobx-state-tree and i would like to actually show the store name when an error appears instead of AnonymousModel.

For example:

```
const SignupModel = types
  .model({
    isUsingFacebook: false,
    birthday: '',
    timeOfBirth: types.maybeNull(types.string),
    placeOfBirth: types.maybeNull(types.string),
    gender: types.maybeNull(types.string),
    password: '',
  })
```

Still gives me an error like

```
Error while converting {...} to AnonymousModel.
```

But i would like to get

```
Error while converting {...} to SignupModel.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply pass a desired name as a first argument to `model` method, like so:

```
const SignupModel = types
  .model('SignupModel', {
    isUsingFacebook: false,
    birthday: '',
    timeOfBirth: types.maybeNull(types.string),
    placeOfBirth: types.maybeNull(types.string),
    gender: types.maybeNull(types.string),
    password: '',
  })
```